# Java Rest Integration Authentication error

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I am a newbie who started to integrate JIRA using Java, following the issues & document, I am trying to get issues using Java.

Everything's fine, but I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.auth.BasicHttpAuthenticationHandler does not implement the requested interface com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.AuthenticationHandler
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
<version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
<artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
<version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>atlassian-public</id>
<url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
<checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
</snapshots>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
</releases>
</repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
<pluginRepository>
<id>atlassian-public</id>
<url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
</releases>
<snapshots>
<checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
</snapshots>
</pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And this is my code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory;

public class Dummy {

private String username;
private String password;
private String jiraUrl;
private JiraRestClient restClient;

private Dummy(String username, String password, String jiraUrl) {
this.username = username;
this.password = password;
this.jiraUrl = jiraUrl;
this.restClient = getJiraRestClient();
}

private JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient() {
return new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(getJiraUri(), this.username,
this.password);
}

private URI getJiraUri() {
return URI.create(this.jiraUrl);
}

private Issue getIssue(String issueKey) {
return restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue(issueKey).claim();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Dummy myJiraClient = new Dummy("username", "password", "http://localhost:8080/secure/WelcomeToJIRA.jspa");
String issueKey = issueKey;
Issue issue = myJiraClient.getIssue(issueKey);
System.out.println(issue.getDescription());

myJiraClient.restClient.close();
}


}
```

I didn't find any solution for the error, also I don't know where I am wrong. It would be appreciated if someone helps me out where I am wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think, it is a dependency conflict. By using mvn dependency:tree command,.. can
analyse and find out.

Also I checked this sample (client) in atlassion bitbucket. In this example, atlassian.httpclient.version is **2.0.0**. Hope this would help.

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client/src/master/pom.xml

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client/src/75a64c9d81aad7d8bd9beb11e098148407b13cae/test/src/test/java/samples/ExampleCreateIssuesAsynchronous.java?at=master&_ga=2.100062872.72364915.1593881496-21279827.1593881496

Comment: yeah it was a dependency problem, it's working fine as standalone, I am trying to get an issue dynamically, I am trying to send a request using postman, the call isn't getting called, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Fine, If you are getting 401 error (Unauthorized), please check this url https://community.atlassian.com/t5/New-to-JSD-questions/calling-JIRA-REST-API-from-POSTMAN/qaq-p/1073199. Otherwise, the service endpoint could be a different one.